# V-Lookup and the number of cells that match a criteria

Tags: excel

I've got a list of names in Sheet 1, Column A for which I am trying to determine program eligibility.

In Sheet 2, Columns F, I, J and K, I have entered data that will tell me if they are eligible or not.

In Sheet 1, Column Q, I would like to place a formula that searches Sheet 2, Column A for the name used in Sheet 1, Column A.

Then I want it to look at that row and tell me if 3 of the 4 values found in Sheet 2, Columns F, I, J and K are equal to or lesser than 4.

Any ideas as to how I can do that?

Comment: Please include test data and expected output.

Comment: Last time I checked, Excel formulas were off-topic for SO?

Comment: @pnuts Well, okay then.